# Get image uri and display it with Coil in Compose (Android)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, uri, coil, android-compose-image

I'm trying to fetch image uri and then display it in my application with coil.

```
var imageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
val launcher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
            imageUri = uri
        }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            //here we are going to add logic for picking image
            launcher.launch(
                "image/*"
            )

        }, content = {
            Text(text = "Select Image From Gallery")
        })
        Log.d(TAG, "ClientCardItem: $imageUri")
        Text(text = imageUri.toString())
```

I made this just to check if i fetched uri. I got result like this:
"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A18", i put it to string.

This is for image display:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data  = Uri.parse(uri)  // or ht
    )
    ,
    contentDescription = "123",
    modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp).width(200.dp),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
)
```

I know that I dont have .jpg or .png or something else to display it properly. My question is how to get that format to display picture I picked.

EDIT:
rememberAsyncImagePainter, rememberImagePainter or AsyncImage are not found ?

After I updated to:

implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:2.2.2"

On AsyncImage() -> Unresolved reference: AsyncImage

Answer (score 1):

To display the image just use:

```
AsyncImage(model = imageUri, contentDescription = "Picture")
```

or:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(imageUri),
    contentDescription = "Picture",
)
```